# Vue active class v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a question about v-for. Why do I have to return `this.activeClass = {...this.activeClass}` to update the component? Why component didn't update after this line.

```
if (this.activeClass[index]) {
                this.activeClass[index] = false;
            } else {
                this.activeClass[index] = true;
            }
```

I want set background to red on click on v-for element

Template:

```
 <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div
                    v-for="(quote, i) in quotes"
                    :key="i"
                    @click="del(i)"
                    :class="{red: activeClass[i]}"
                    class="quote col-3"
                >
                    {{ quote }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ["quotes"],
    data: function() {
        return {
            activeClass: {}
        };
    },
    methods: {
        del(index) {
            if (this.activeClass[index]) {
                this.activeClass[index] = false;
            } else {
                this.activeClass[index] = true;
            }
            this.activeClass = {...this.activeClass};
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Read vue.js reactivity docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Change the `del(index)` method to this : `Vue.set(this.activeClass, index, !this.activeClass[index])` This should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuejs is not reactive on deep object. look at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others have said, I can't help but feel that you're over-complicating this slightly. You're already looping over an object `(quotes)`, why not apply an active property to those instead?

#### HTML

```
<div
        v-for="(quote, i) in quotes"
        :key="i"
        @click="del(quote)"
        :class="{active: quote.active}"
        class="quote col-3"
>
    {{ quote }}
</div>
```

#### Method Change

```
del(quote) {
    quote.active = !quote.active;
}
```

#### New CSS

```
.quote.active{
    background-color: red;
}
```